# Change WPF Property before and after running a function

Tags: c#, wpf, isenabled

Running this code:

```
Window_Abfrage.IsEnabled = false;
Alert(Cloud.UserExists(new Cloud.User(TextBox_Cloud_User_UserName.Text)).ToString()); // unimportant for the problem; just a function causing a few seconds of time
Window_Abfrage.IsEnabled = true;
```

doesnt work how I want. 
The idea is, that the window is disabled, while the function Cloud.UserExists is running, but in fact the window is enabled all the time and just at the end it switches to disabled, only a short time before the alert is shown. Do you know why?

Best Regards!

Comment: Is that method being executed asynchronously? Also, did you try to just call `Refresh()` on your form after disabling it?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `Task` or `Thread` for a long running operation?

Comment: What do you mean with Refresh()? "Window_Abfrage.Refresh()" does not exist...
No, I dont want a second thread, the whole window should be disabled while the method is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because UI freezes (due to long running task you are invoking) *before* it can render as disabled. In .NET 2.0/3.5 The best way to achieve desired behavior is to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

1. In its `DoWork` event (which is executed on separate thread) you
   should run your long running task.
2. In its `RunWorkerCompleted` event (executed on UI thread) you should
   enable Window.
3. In button click event, run the `BackgroundWorker` this way:

   Window_Abfrage.IsEnabled = false;
   backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Promlem is, that when I try to set Window_Abfrage.IsEnabled = true; in the BackgroundWorker Method, nothing happens, the Backgroundworker doesn´t do that. Do you know why?

Comment: @Simsso you should set the flag only on UI thread: either button click event (to false) or RunWorkerCompleted event (to true).

Comment: Claiming BackgroundWorker would be best is not entirely correct. It depends on the .Net version you're using. For 4.0 it would be Task, for 4.5 async. At least in that order it results in way less boilerplate code.

Comment: @AndreasMüller You're right. I guess I'm just too .NET 3.5-centric ;)